# check if an element already exist in a linked list in c

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct, linked-list

Suppose I have a linked list that stores a book struct and the next node pointer:

```
struct book {
    unsigned short  size_of_content;
    unsigned short  price;
    unsigned char  *content;
};

struct list {
    struct book p;
    struct list *next;
};
```

And when I am constructing the linked list, I will check if the new book's price is the same as the price of one of the books that have been linked. Basically make sure that there is no duplicate prices.

I have an idea of constructing an price array and compare the new price with the existing ones. However, since C does not support unlimited size of arrays, I dont think my way is a good idea. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Why make an extra array? Why not just go through the linked-list and check the prices? Also: while no programming-language in the universe is ever going to support *unlimited-length* arrays (not counting lazily-evaluated languages), C like many other languages does support *variable-length* arrays.

Comment: If you don't want to repeat elements, making an ordered tree (time O(logn)) instead of a list might be a good idea. Otherwise you will have to go through the entire list every time, which is O(n).

Comment: A linked list is a poor choice in this case. Use some data structure to keep books ordered with `O(log(n))` access time (e.g. binary search tree), it's blazingly fast to check for an existing price.

Comment: doing this in linked list could not be done better than O(n). You'd better to use an array-list instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an array or all that jazz you could just check if the price already exists in the linked list. Another method could be to add the price as you are adding it to the linked list to a dynamically sized array using the **malloc** function. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

But that seems inefficient because you will have to check the array every single time even as it grows to n size.

I think that would be the better way to do it.

You could even use a better data structure which is based on a linked list and its called a skip list.

Read here on skip lists http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list 
These are actually really cool. Might be worth the time to try and implement this way.

**EDIT**: As the others have commented a binary search tree would be a better data structure for this problem.

Comment: How on earth do you search a linked list using binary search?

Comment: True, for some reason i assumed it was ordered.

Comment: Even if it's ordered, you can't do binary search in a linked list - you can't access random elements easily. Binary search only works in arrays; if this is not flexible enough, a tree structure must be used instead. Pure linked lists, even if ordered, are not searchable in `O(log(n))` time, period.

Comment: Binary search does not only work on arrays. Counter proof is a "skip list" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

Comment: Hum. That's cool! Never heard of this before. this is awesome. Put this in your answer and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

If your price is an integer, that will be easy: allocate some bytes, initialize them to 0. Before you add a new book with price *m*, check the m-th bit in these bytes, if it is 1, then you have already had the price; if not, add this book and set the m-th bit to 1. In this case, you don't need to go through the linked list again and again to find the price and also the storage cost is limited.

Comment: should I create a *char pointer then? Also, what if there are more than "some bytes" prices in the file I read?

Comment: @LesbianSquirtle, signed short is from 0 to 255, so you only need 256/8=32 bytes. This is a fixed length of memory so you can use array other than linked list.

Comment: Are you saying that the value of variables with type "unsigned short" can only be at most 255?

Comment: @LesbianSquirtle, Yes, unsigned short will be up to 255.

Comment: shorts are at least 16 bits. That means that `unsigned short` will be up to `2^16-1` which is 65536. 255 can be the max. value for unsigned chars, IF chars are 8 bits.