# In C: How to construct a linked list in order based on a variable?

Tags: c, file, struct, io, linked-list

Suppose I am fread()-ing multiple items, each stored in a struct with an integer variable that indicates its order. So something like this:

```
struct book {
    int order;
}
```

And I am also constructing a linked list to contain all the books read, such that the book with the smallest "order" will be the head.

The linked list declaration is as follows:

```
struct list {
    struct book p;
    struct list *next;
}
```

Since the books I am reading are in random order, and there is no previous pointer, how should I make sure that I can find the book with the smallest order and make it the head of my linked list?

This is what I have so far, it just adds them in random order:

```
list *lst, *temp;
struct book buff2;

lst=malloc(sizeof(struct list));

while((nread2=fread(&buff2,sizeof(buff2),1,infp))>0) {

        temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
        temp->p=buff2;
        lst->next=temp;
        lst=temp;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you're the same person who asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741909/check-if-an-element-already-exist-in-a-linked-list-in-c/21742055 - give up on the linked list, use a binary search tree instead.

Comment: It would be better to explain *why* a binary search tree is a better choice than to tell him (or her) to "give up on the linked list."  Also, a binary search tree is slightly more complex than a linked list - so, baby steps might be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep your list in order from least to greatest, you can do the following, though you should keep in mind that this is not the most optimal data structure for this task.

Note, I have neither compiled nor tested this code - it is simply a sound starting point for you to use in moving forward and illustrating the idea of iterators and insertion.

```
// Declare lst (head), item (new item), and a list iterator (iter).
list *lst = NULL, *item = NULL, *iter = NULL; // Initialize all to NULL.
struct book buff2;

while ((nread2 = fread(&buff2, sizeof(buff2), 1, infp)) > 0) { // Read item.
    item = malloc(sizeof(list)); // Allocate node for new item.
    item->p = buff2; // Assignment to the new node data.
    item->next = NULL; // Initialize the next to NULL.

    if (lst == NULL) lst = temp; // Add item to blank list.
    else { // List has items, find insertion point, then insert.
       // lst is always the first item (or head).  iter moves down list.
       iter = lst; 

       // Find the insertion point, taking order into consideration.
       while ((iter->next != NULL) && (iter->p.order < temp->p.order)) 
           iter = iter->next; // Move the iterator down the list.

       // We now just need to insert our new node into the list. Adjust nexts.
       item->next = iter->next; // New item takes over the insertion item next.
       iter->next = item; // Change insertion next to point to the new item.
    }
}
```